# How to set 403 Forbidden on single page via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

How to use 403 forbidden for **1 single page**. I have been using the following code *below* on directory level like on my WordPress site **/wp-content/**, **/wp-includes/** & it works. But How to *achieve for a single file* like **/example-service.html** so that when anyone visit the page **/example-service.html** it returns 403 forbidden (in .htaccess)

```
<files>
order allow, deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `RewriteRule` to redirect `/example-service.html` to `403` error.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^example-service.html$ - [R=403]
```

Comment: Applied on Global .htaccess but--- **Didn't seem to work**. Page still allowed to be viewed to user

    Applied like this:
------------------------------------

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^treatment-of-tendon-and-muscle/$ - [R=403]